# MeshLab 2021.05 released options

Tags: meshlab

With the update of 2021/5, the "pre-open options" for loading ".txt" files is no longer displayed. Where did it go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go in Tools->Options and set the "MeshLab::System::showPreOpenParameterDialog" to 'true'.

It has been hidden